# Normal Distribution, Standard Deviation - 1 family member of the mean

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

[image]

I don't understand what this even means:

> 1 family member of the mean

Please explain like I'm 5, thank you!

Comment: **within** one family member of the mean; not differing from the mean by more than one.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks, so if the mean is a then it should be a+-1?

Comment: No, it should be at most $a+1$ and at least $a-1$.

Comment: I appreciate it! So the correct answers are #2 and #3. But why #2 though? Is it because of the words "**more likely**"? Furthermore, would it also be possible to use "**within 3 family members of the mean**"? Please help me understand it, thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, it's because of the words, "more likely".